# In how many ways can 3 monitors be oriented and placed on a desk?

Tags: combinatorics

There are $3$ distinguishable monitors and each monitor can be oriented in $4$ unique ways. In how many ways can you arrange them on a desk? ($3$ positions in total)

My attempt:

There are $3!$ ways to arrange the monitors without worrying about their orientation. For each arrangement there are $4^3$ ways to orient the monitors since each monitor can be oriented in 4 unique ways. Therefore there are $3! \times 4^3 = 384 $ ways to arrange the monitors

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Agreed. Your answer is correct!

Comment: Thank you, I was skeptical after many trials in my own head :)

Comment: @Damien I posted a communitywiki answer (which avoids giving me and others rep for having done little to no work) so that the answer may be accepted to remove this from the queue of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct.  This is seen from direct application of the multiplication principle and by setting up a sequence of choices as follows:

- Choose where to place monitor A (3 choices)
- Choose where to place monitor B (2 remaining choices)
- Choose where to place monitor C (1 remaining choice)
- Choose the orientation of monitor A (4 choices)
- Choose the orientation of monitor B (4 choices)
- Choose the orientation of monitor C (4 choices)

By multiplication principle, the total number of ways is the product of the number of choices at each step for a combined total of $3!4^3 = 384$ number of ways to arrange the monitors on the desk.

Simplifications to the sequence of choices may of course be made when you are more comfortable with making them such as choosing the locations of all monitors simultaneously (via permutations) and choosing the orientation of all monitors simultaneously (via powers) as you have correctly shown above.